# ng-repeat values in single input with comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have list array.Inside that I have one nested array called `types`.
I am trying to show `types.work` inside an input field with comma separated.

This is what I have tried:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function(){
 $scope.list=[
   {
     "name":"john",
     "types":[
       {"work":"aa"},
       {"work":"bb"}
     ]
   }
 ];
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="list.name">
   <label ng-repeat="data in list.types">{{data.work}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me that how to use ng-repeat values in single input?.

Comment: `console.log($scope.list[0].types.reduce((a, b) => a.work + ', ' + b.work));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use multiple `ng-repeat` to access the nested array.

```
 <label ng-repeat="data in list">
      <label  ng-repeat="d in data.types">

        {{d.work}}
      </label>

</label>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function(){
 $scope.list=[
   {
     "name":"john",
     "types":[
       {"work":"aa"},
       {"work":"bb"}
     ]
   }
 ];  
 $scope.name = $scope.list[0].types.map((o) => o.work)
  $scope.name =  $scope.name.join(",")
 }
 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">
   <label ng-repeat="data in list">
      <label  ng-repeat="d in data.types">
      
        {{d.work}}
      </label>
   
   </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function(){
 $scope.list=[
   {
     "name":"john",
     "types":[
       {"work":"aa"},
       {"work":"bb"}
     ]
   }
 ];
 
  $scope.input_model_value  = ''
  var  temp = []
  $scope.list.forEach(function(t1){
      t1.types.forEach(function(val){
      temp.push(val.work)
    })
  })
   $scope.input_model_value = temp.join(',')
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="input_model_value">
   <label ng-repeat="data in list.types">{{data.work}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case  You want some other solution. You can iterate over your array in JS file and assign the value to your input model.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="listData">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function(){
 $scope.list=[
   {
     "name":"john",
     "types":[
       {"work":"aa"},
       {"work":"bb"}
     ]
   }
 ];
 $scope.listData = "";
 for(var i=0;i<$scope.list[0].types.length;i++){
 
 if($scope.listData!= undefined){
 $scope.listData = $scope.listData+","+$scope.list[0].types[i].work;
 }
 
 
 }
      }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the list an array so you can use ng-repeat in ng-repeat or you can directly use array first object like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="list[0].name">
<label ng-repeat="data in list[0].types">{{data.work}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</label>
```